# Parse Cloud 400 Bad Request with 141

Tags: javascript, parse-cloud-code

I have simple cloud code with hello world

```
//on parse cloud main.js
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {
   response.success("Hi");
});
```

([main.js in cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvskb.jpg)) and from my parse JS app i have this

```
Parse.initialize('KEY', 'KEY');
Parse.Cloud.run('hello').then(function(response) {
   // response
   console.log(response);
});
```

After i request this parse cloud hello function it response 400 bad request with

```
{"code":141,"error":"function not found"}
```

Please help me.

Comment: its because parse server error

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to set the URL in there.